# Removing green Xs and red lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry, topology

I'm using QGIS 2.18.15 and have somehow ended up with the following on my screen. I've deselected every layer and these green X's and red lines persist. I cannot "undo" to remove them.

What are they & how do I get rid of them?

They may have originally been related to a duplicate node or something like that, but I have no idea what's going on.

[image]

Comment: They appear when you build an invalid geometry, such as self-intersecting ones

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are in the middle of editing or creating a new line feature. If you toggle the layer visibility you still see the half-created feature, and if you toggle editing off in that layer you'll still see it!

If you re-activate the layer visibility of whichever layer it is, and re-enable editing, you might find you need to finish creating the element before saving the layer. Delete the feature if you don't need it.

The green crosses are self-intersections that show this is an invalid geometry - you should also have seen a warning like `"Add feature: segments 0 and 2 of line 0 intersect at -2.35695756492, 0.44230006192 Geometry has 1 errors. Validation finished"`

Comment: I've occasionally encountered a similar issue where either the digitizing red lines or the identify feature red outline lingered on the map after the tool was deactivated. In these cases the problem was solved by closing and re-opening the program.

Answer (score 2):

As stated above it is unfinished editing. Once you have selected editing the layer again you right click on it and cancel current edits, that should do the trick.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please consider not leaving duplicate answers to already answered questions, since it adds no value or new insight to the problem and its solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the red lines or green X persist even after there's nothing editable anymore and even if the offending layers are turned editable and not editable again.

The solution is to use the identify tool on the offending graphics and they go poof.

Not a fix, but a decent workaround for a rare bug.

Answer (score -2):

Im new to qgis and I have run into this error.  It originated with a vectorized layer, that has since been deleted, and the green x's persist.

I even went so far as export my raster layers out to start a new project, but they go with the geotiff for some reason.

They clearly state that its an intersection of lines, yet there are no lines in the file that can intersect.

You know the only solution I could find?  Reinstall the damn program. Works like a charm.

I already hate this program so much.

Comment: This bug was solved long ago. Since you reinstalled it, take the opportunity to update.