# What a green X means in QGIS

Tags: qgis

[image]When I finished splitting features, the green X appeared. But, I don't know what it means.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/azO8j.png]

[image]

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot of the original data and also the tool you used?

Comment: Of course!!!I've re-added a screenshot.

Comment: Watch here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270176/removing-green-xs-and-red-lines-in-qgis

Answer (score 5):

Those are validation errors. Check out the geometries at those locations.

Answer (score 1):

In your case these are duplicate points. I don't know why splitting sometimes makes duplicate points, but it does. It's fairly rare in my experience. You can use the Vertex editing tool [image: vertex editing tool] to delete them individually. Alternatively, Repair Geometries (in the Processing Toolbox) will get rid of all of them but it makes a new layer.